# Writing to a topic from a Processor in a Spring Cloud Streams Kafka Stream application

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am using the Processor API to do some low level processing into a state store. The point is I also need to write into a topic after storing into the store. How can it be done in a Spring Cloud Streams Kafka applications?

```
@Bean
fun processEvent() = Consumer<KStream<EventId, EventValue>> { event ->

    event.map{
        ...
    }.process(ProcessorSupplier {

            object : Processor<EventId, MappedEventValue> {

                private lateinit var store: KeyValueStore<EventId, MappedEventValue>

                override fun init(context: ProcessorContext) {
                    store = context.getStateStore("event-store") as KeyValueStore<EventId, MappedEventValue>
                }

                override fun process(key: EventId, value: MappedEventValue) {
                    ...
                    store.put(key, processedMappedEventValue)

                    //TODO Write into a topic
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The `process()` method is a terminal operation that does not allow you to emit data downstream. Instead, you can use `transform()` though (it's basically the same a `process()` but allows you to emit data downstream); or depending on your app, `transformValues()` or `flatTransform()` etc.

Using `transform()` you get `KStream` back, that you can write into a topic.

Comment: As stated in the answer, using `transform` allows you to get a `KStream` which you can send to the topic. In that case, you might want to use `Function` as the return type. If you have a use case that must use the `process()` method, then I guess you still can send to the topic using `KafkaTemplate` from Spring Kafka directly or using the `StreamBrdige` API from Spring Cloud Stream. But, using transformer as suggested is far better IMO.